# How to efficiently get the counts of values (from a list) less than some index number?

Tags: kdb

It is hard for me to describe in words what this function does, but I have some working code.

```
f:{[n;k] sum flip k </: til n}
i:i: 3 4 6 7 13;
f[30;i]
0 0 0 0 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5i
```

In am concerned that the `flip` operation may be expensive for large input values. Is there a way to do this without the flip that is more efficient?

Being just as concise would be a nice-to-have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your inputs you can achieve the same result with

```
{[n;k] k binr til n}
```

This should work so long as `k` remains in ascending order.
Docs for binr are here: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/bin/

Answer (score 1):

Seans answer is probably more efficient (test it), but why not change your each-right to each-left to avoid the flip?

```
q)g:{[n;k] sum k<\:til n}
q)f[30;i]~g[30;i]
1b
```